# NullReferenceException when creating a list from a ListBox item

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nullreferenceexception

In my app I've come across something that I simply cannot get to work. I use this code to add text to a list and save it for each textbox in a listbox. this is my code:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Save the lecture
    int amount = paragraphListBox.Items.Count();

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        // save the paragraphs, one by one

        // Get the current item
        var current = paragraphListBox.Items[i] as TextBox;
        String paragraph = current.Text.ToString();

        // Add the paragraph to the list
        paragraphList.Add(paragraph);

        try
        {
            // Try to remove a setting
            settings.Remove(lectureName + "-lecture");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        try
        {
            // Try to add a setting
            settings.Add(lectureName + "-lecture", paragraphList);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        try
        {
            // Try to save the settings
            settings.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The line: "paragraphList.Add(paragraph);", throws a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I bet `paragraphList` is `null` when you are adding paragraph

Comment: you need to init paragraphList using new.

Comment: What is paragraphList? paragraphList = new ...

Comment: Yeah, I found out - thought I had already done that. Sorry:) See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot a very important line of code...:

```
        // Initialize paragraphList
        paragraphList = new List<String>();
```

Comment: Yes, totally forgot it